# How can I serve a .zip through an API Gateway with a Python Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**Context:** I have some log files in an S3 bucket that I need to retrieve. The permissions on the bucket prevent me from downloading them directly from the S3 bucket console. I need a "backdoor" approach to retrieve the files. I have an API Gateway setup to hit a Lambda, which will figure out what files to retrieve and get them from the S3 bucket. However, the files are over 10 MB and the AWS API Gateway has a maximum payload size of 10 MB. Now, I need a way to compress the files and serve them to the client as a downloadable zip.

```py
import json
import boto3
import zipfile
import zlib
import os

S3 = boto3.resource('s3')
BUCKET = S3.Bucket(name="my-bucket")

TEN_MEGA_BYTES = 1000000000

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # utilize Lambda's temporary storage (512 MB) 
    retrieved = zipfile.ZipFile("/tmp/retrieved.zip", mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9)

    for bucket_obj in BUCKET.objects.all():

        # logic to decide which file I want is done here

        log_file_obj = BUCKET.Object(bucket_obj.key).get()

        # get the object's binary encoded content (a bytes object)
        content = log_file_obj["Body"].read()

        # write the content to a file within the zip
        # writestr() requires a bytes or str object
        retrieved.writestr(bucket_obj.key, content)

    # close the zip
    retrieved.close()

    # visually checking zip size for debugging
    zip_size = os.path.getsize("/tmp/retrieved.zip")
    print("{} bytes".format(zip_size), "{} percent of 10 MB".format(zip_size / TEN_MEGA_BYTES * 100))

    return {
        "header": {
            "contentType": "application/zip, application/octet-stream",
            "contentDisposition": "attachment, filename=retrieved.zip",
            "contentEncoding": "deflate"
        },
        "body": retrieved
    }

    # return retrieved
```

I have tried returning the zipfile object directly and within a JSON structure with headers that are supposed to be mapped from the integration response to the method response (i.e. the headers I'm setting programmatically in the Lambda should be mapped to the response headers that the client actually receives). In either case, I get a marshal error.

```
Response:
{
    "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: <zipfile.ZipFile [closed]> is not JSON serializable",
    "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
}
```

I have done a lot of tinkering in the API Gateway in the AWS Console trying to set different combinations of headers and/or content types, but I am stuck. I'm not entirely sure what would be the correct header/content-type combination.

From the above error message, it appears like Lambda can only return JSON structures but I am unable to confirm either way.

Comment: Side-question: What is the issue you are facing with permissions? Is it because you have access to only a specific Bucket, or a directory within a Bucket? If so, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access objects directly, or possibly jump to a specific URL in the Amazon S3 management console to access the bucket/folder that you are allowed to access. Can you provide more details on the issue you are facing?

Comment: My client is restricting permissions on that bucket in the deployment environment we are working in. They have restricted Console and CLI access to where we cannot upload/download objects to that bucket. If we use a native AWS service to interact with the bucket, we don't have that limitation. As it stands now, we are only able to contact AWS, put in a ticket, and have them get the files for us. However, that is horribly inefficient when trying to debug.

Comment: Have you tried using a URL that takes you directly to the bucket, bypassing the default S3 bucket listing? For example: `https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/my-bucket/?region=us-west-2&tab=overview` This will not require permissions to list all buckets, and will possibly work for you. How about using the AWS CLI to access the bucket?

Comment: Yes, I am able to go directly to the bucket with a similar link as above. However, the permissions set by the client still prevents us from downloading/uploading files to that bucket through the AWS Management Console or the CLI. I can go to the bucket itself and see that there are objects in the S3 bucket, I just can't download them.

Answer (score 4):

I got to the point of being able to return a compressed JSON payload, not a downloadable .zip file, but that is good enough for the time being. My team and I are looking into requesting a time-limited pre-signed URL for the S3 bucket that will allow us to bypass the permissions for a limited time to access the files. Even with the compression, we expect to someday reach the point where even the compressed payload is too large for the API Gateway to handle. We also discovered that Lambda has a smaller payload limit than even the API Gateway, [Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), 6 MB (synchronous).

**Solution**:
This article was a huge help, [Lambda Compression](https://medium.com/@janrubio/api-gateway-lambda-compression-86f61deed6a5). The main thing that was missing was using "Lambda Proxy Integration." When configuring the API Gateway Integration Request, choose "Use Lambda Proxy Integration." That will limit your ability to use any mapping templates on your method request and will mean that you have to return a specific structure from your Lambda function. Also, ensure content encoding is enabled in the settings of the API Gateway and with 'application/json' specified as an acceptable Binary Media Type.
Then, when sending the request, use these headers:

```
Accept-Encoding: application/gzip,
Accept: application/json
```

```py
import json
import boto3
import gzip
import base64
from io import BytesIO

S3 = boto3.resource('s3')
BUCKET = S3.Bucket(name="my-bucket")


def gzip_b64encode(data):
    compressed = BytesIO()
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed, mode='w') as f:
        json_response = json.dumps(data)
        f.write(json_response.encode('utf-8'))
    return base64.b64encode(compressed.getvalue()).decode('ascii')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # event body is JSON string, this is request body
    req_body = json.loads(event["body"])

    retrieved_data = {}

    for bucket_obj in BUCKET.objects.all():

        # logic to decide what file to grab based on request body done here

        log_file_obj = BUCKET.Object(bucket_obj.key).get()

        content = log_file_obj["Body"].read().decode("UTF-8")

        retrieved_data[bucket_obj.key] = json.loads(content)

    # integration response format
    return {
        "isBase64Encoded": True,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        "body": gzip_b64encode(retrieved_data)
    }
```